# Javascript create images on canvas in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am Looping through my Images and try to put all in my canvas but I get this error:

My Html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <canvas id="signature-canvas" class="signature-canvas"></canvas>

</div>
```

> signatures.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D':  The provided value is not of type 
>   '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or
>   HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or
>   OffscreenCanvas)'
>       at Image.images.(anonymous function).onload (http://localhost/app/public/js/signatures.js:121:25)

my javascript

```
var canvasModule = {

    elements: {
        canvas: document.getElementById('signature-canvas')
    },

    render: function () {
        this.createImageOnCanvas();
    },

    getCanvasContext: function () {
        return this.elements.canvas.getContext('2d');
    },

    getCanvasWidth: function () {
        return this.elements.canvas.width;
    },

    getCanvasHeight: function () {
        return this.elements.canvas.height;
    },

    createImageOnCanvas: function () {

        var itemWidth = this.getCanvasWidth() / 7;
        var itemHeight = this.getCanvasHeight() / 3;

        var u = 0;
        var context = this.getCanvasContext();
        var images = [];
        var imagesWidth = [];
        var imagesHeight = [];

        for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            images[i] = new Image();

            images[i].src = 'images/sample/1'+i+'.png';

            imagesWidth[i] = images[i].width;
            imagesHeight[i] = images[i].height;

            images[i].onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(images[i], u, 0, itemWidth, itemHeight);
            }

            u = u + itemWidth;
        }

    }

}


$(document).ready(canvasModule.render());
```

Comment: I got your script working when image is not defined using an array, maybe the onload is not working propperly with an array? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpZpXY?editors=0010

Comment: Line 29: function this.getCanvasContext() doesn't exist, I replaced this with this.getCanvas().

Comment: @JoostMeijer the function does exist, so your script works now?

Comment: Oh you're right, I accidently removed a part copying to my editor. But yes the script works, look at the codepen.io.

Comment: Rule of thumb: never create a function inside a loop. This is a classic case of variable hoisting. In your case, `var i` is hoisted for callbacks. [please read this](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
 images[i].onload = function () {           
     context.drawImage(images[i], u, 0, itemWidth, itemHeight);
 }
```

because `i` is just a `var` which is hoisted to the top of the function and whose value will be incorrect by the time the callback is invoked, instead of a `let` variable.

Your `u` variable for setting the horizontal offset suffers from the same problem.

If your JS environment doesn't support `let` you can use this instead:

```
images[i].onload = (function(i, u) {
     context.drawImage(images[i], u, 0, itemWidth, itemHeight);
}).bind(this, i, u);
```

Comment: better use `this`.

Comment: @Kaiido what do you mean?  The `.bind` call already preserves `this`.

Comment: Ok this worked, but all Images are stacked now instead of being next to each other any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Jaan did you use my updated answer where I pass `u` into the callback as well?

Comment: @Alnitak yes I used that one somehow it does not increment?

Comment: I mean using `drawImage(this, ...` is always clearer than `drawImage(images[i], ...).bind(...)`

Comment: @Jaan Have you used `let` or `.bind`?    If the former, you have to declare `let u = 0` as well.

Comment: @Kaiido true, except in this case the OP needs to pass another variable as well.   An IIFE would also work, although `.bind` is IMHO cleaner.

Comment: Nevermind it was my fault it works nice

Comment: Well using `this` still avoids the bind of `i`, but anyway, if it were my code, I would split all this in two steps: load all, draw all. Only two declared functions and no hoisting nightmare, `u` would simply become `i * itemWidth` where `i` is the iterator of the draw all func.

Comment: @Alnitak btw do you have an idea why is Image Quality is so bad in my script?

Comment: @Jaan I expect you've got a mismatch between the CSS width and height of the image elements compared to the actual onscreen size (which AFAICR defaults to 300x300)